# Data isn't getting pushed to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datatables

I've been able to display JSON data (local file) into each row in my table, and when the data's corresponding checkbox is checked I want to push those selected values into an array. The end goal is to display the array in a div, but not until I'm able to see that the array is being populated.

### JS snippet:

```
($("#km-table-id tbody tr")).append($("<input />", {"type": "checkbox"}).addClass("checkbox-class"));

let table = $("#km-table-id").DataTable();
    let favesArr = [];

    $(".checkbox-class").on("click", "tr", function() {
      let data = table.row(this).data();
      for (var i = 0; i < favesArr.length; i++) {
        favesArr.push($(data).text());
        $("#myFave.hs-gc-header").append(favesArr[i]);
      }      
      console.log(data); // this was showing the selected data a short time ago, but not anymore  

    });

    console.log(favesArr); // only showing empty
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your last line will always print an empty array because you are only filling it in an event handler.

Secondly, you are using `i < favesArr.length` as your loop condition. `favesArr` is empty here yet, if not filled in other parts of the code. The loop body thus is never executed. You probably wanted `data.length` here.

Last but not least, you may want to push only `data[i]` and not the whole array into your `favesArray`.

Comment: I moved the `favesArr.push(` line above the `for loop.` Nothing's changed, but am I headed in the right direction?

Comment: @Bodrov Your issue is that you're only pushing stuff on the click event but what is under the click event is immediately fired after setting the event listener. If you want it to work on execution of the event handler when the variable is changed then move your `console.log` statement up in your click handler.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you capture whether the checkbox is checked. You can check if the item is already in the array by grabbing the data index.

Not sure what your HTML looks like...

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.appendText = function(text) { return this.text(this.text() + text); };
  $.fn.appendHtml = function(html) { return this.html(this.html() + html); };
})(jQuery);

const $table = $('#km-table-id');

$table.find('tbody tr').append($("<input>", { type: 'checkbox', class : 'checkbox-class'}));

let table = $table.DataTable();
let favesArr = [];

$table.on('click', '.checkbox-class', function(e) {
  let data = table.row(this.parentNode).data(),
      checked = $(this).is(':checked'),
      dataIndex = favesArr.indexOf(data);
  if (checked) {
    if (dataIndex === -1) {
      favesArr.push(data); // Add item
    }
  } else {
    if (dataIndex > -1) {
      favesArr.splice(dataIndex, 1); // Remove item
    }
  }
  $('#myFave.hs-gc-header').appendHtml('>> ' + favesArr.map(x => x.join(', ')).join('; ') + '<br/>');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #666;
}
.table-wrapper {
  background: #fff;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

#myFave.hs-gc-header {
  background: #fff;
  width: 81%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  height: 5em;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<div class="table-wrapper">
  <table id="km-table-id">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="myFave" class="hs-gc-header"></div>
```

Comment: I updated my code and upon clicking a box I'm getting x.join is not a function in the console. As far as I can tell my code is identical to yours, so perhaps it's something else? Thanks for creating the table in your code snippet, btw.

Comment: @Bodrov `x` represents an individual cell value within each row.

Comment: Quick update: I moved `console.log(favesArr)` to a different spot and can see that the array is getting populated, but the array isn't being appended to the div. I'll add/remove/rearrange code to see what's up.